# Will creating new Private Keys impact Apps which are already in App Store?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, itunes

I have lost my private key and I want to create new one for a new app that I will be submit to the App store.

But I also have an app on App Store. If I change my private key, how will it impact that app?

Please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No problems with doing so.  I had to do it about a year ago for a client's app when they couldn't get the key from the previous developer. Just make sure you go in and redo all of the certs and provisioning  too.